# Replace the references that do not have the extension with Grunt task runner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs, browser-cache

I am trying to apply cache busting using a Grunt package called grunt-cache-bust https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust. However, the problem I am facing is to replace the references from my source file that do not have the extension, for example, I want to replace the "ProfileCtrl" reference from the module.js file. Is there any way I can do this?

Below is my code:

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    cacheBust: {
        options: {
            assets: ['**/**/*'],
            baseDir: './app/',
            createCopies: true,
            deleteOriginal: false
        },
        taskName: {
            src: ['**/module.js']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cache-bust');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['cacheBust']);
```

module.js

```
 define(['angular',
'angular-couch-potato',
'angular-ui-router',
'angular-moment'
], function (ng, couchPotato) {

"use strict";

var module = ng.module('app.profile', ['ui.router']);

couchPotato.configureApp(module)

module.config(function ($stateProvider, $couchPotatoProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('app.profile', {
            abstract: true,
            data: {
                title: 'User Profile'
            }
        })
        .state('app.profile.show', {
            url: '/profile/show/:studentId',
            data: {
                title: 'User Profile'
            },
            param: ['studentId'],
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    templateUrl: "app/profile/views/index.html",
                    resolve: {
                        deps: $couchPotatoProvider.resolveDependencies([
                            'profile/controllers/ProfileCtrl'
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }
        })
});

module.run(function ($couchPotato) {
    module.lazy = $couchPotato;
});
return module;
});
```

Comment: Is /profile/controllers/ProfileCtrl under your `baseDir` (./app)?

Comment: Hi there! Any solution to your problem? I have the exactly the same problem in an application developed with SmartAdmin Bootstrap/Angular 1.5.x.